# Commonclipse for Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a Visual Studio plugin/tool/snippet for .NET that is similar to commonclipse for the java eclipse platform that automatically generates the ToString(), Equals(), GetHashCode() methods for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) will do it. (not a free tool unfortunately)

Here's a [blog post](http://blog.excastle.com/2007/02/22/resharper-day-22-generating-code-with-altins/) about that specific functionality:

Comment: Alt+Insert! I've been using ReSharper for ages, and I never knew about that.